# How to pass a search pattern starting with $ to less on the command line

Tags: search, less, parameter

I just tried to pass a search pattern starting with `$` to less:

```
less +/'\$l' myfile.pl
```

and I got

```
There is no -l option ("less --help" for help)
```

After reading the manual, I tried the alternate `-p`-option

```
less -p'\$l' myfile.pl
```

and got the same error.

Then I found, that (n.b. the space after `-p`)

```
less -p '\$l' myfile.pl
```

works, i.e. opens the file without error message and jumps to first occurrence of `$l`.

The long option variant `--pattern=$l` does not work

```
less --pattern='\$l' myfile.pl
There is no -l option ("less --help" for help)
```

whereas space instead of `=` works

```
less --pattern '\$l' myfile.pl
```

This is

```
less -V
less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman
```

on openSUSE Leap 42.3

Now the question: is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's caused by a *feature*. From `man less`:

> Some  options like -k or -D require a string to follow the option letter.  The string for that option is considered to end when a dollar
>          sign ($) is found.  For example, you can set two -D options on MS-DOS like this:
>
> ```
> LESS="Dn9.1$Ds4.1"
> ```

So you could do:

```
LESS='ppattern$i' PAGER=less man less
```

To start `less`, looking for `pattern` case-insensitively.

[`--use-backslash` may be used to allow `\` to escape that `$`](/a/438125).

Now, while it makes sense for the `$LESS` variable, it makes little sense for arguments to options on the command line. In that, it could be seen as a bug which you may want to report.

Also note that that `$` processing only occurs when that  `$` occurs in the same argument as that containing the option which explains the discrepancy between your `-p '\$l'` vs `-p'\$l'` and `--pattern '\$l'` vs `--pattern='\$l'` causing confusion and more justification that it may be seen as a bug.

Note that you'll also have problems for:

```
less -p' foo'
```

Where `less` looks for `"foo"` instead of `" foo"` (again use `-p ' foo'` instead). Look at the `scan_option()` function in `options.c` in the source for details.

Comment: but this does not really explain the different behaviour when called with a space or not for the short `-p` resp. space or `=` for `--pattern`

Comment: @mararm, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

From `man less`:

> ```
>    --use-backslash
>           This option changes the interpretations of options which  follow
>           this one.  After the --use-backslash option, any backslash in an
>           option string is removed and the following  character  is  taken
>           literally.   This  allows a dollar sign to be included in option
>           strings.
> ```

We then need to escape both the backslash and the dollar, so

```
less --use-backslash +'/\\\$l' myfile.pl
```